# how to jump directly to an org-headline?

Tags: org-mode, completion

If I'm in an org file, I want a command that narrows a candidate list, in ivy/helm style, comprised of all org headlines in the file and lets me choose the headline, through fuzzy searching, to which I want to jump to. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Org Manual node on [Motion](http://orgmode.org/manual/Motion.html#Motion) gives a somewhat laconic description of the built-in command `org-goto` (default binding: `C-c C-j`), whose behaviour can easily be customised to achieve the desired effect:

1. Inspect the documentation of the customisable variable listed at the end of this manual node: `C-h v org-goto-interface RET`
2. If you are happy to forgo the default `org-goto` behaviour of incrementally searching through the buffer's outline, you can switch to picking a headline via completion:

   ```el
   (setq org-goto-interface 'outline-path-completion)
   ```
3. Users of completion packages like `ido`/`ivy`/`helm` will probably want to change the following setting in order to see the whole target path at once:

   ```el
   (setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
   ```

   See [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/986) for more discussion.

This approach has the added benefit (over using, say, `helm`-specific functionality) of working with all completion frameworks that plug into the default `completing-read`, including, as I can personally confirm, `ivy`.

ADDENDUM:

When using the `outline-path-completion` interface to the `org-goto` command as described in this answer, the customisable variable `org-goto-max-level` determines the maximum depth of headlines to offer.

EDIT:

I found an older, relevant question with useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15011703/3084001

CLARIFICATION (as prompted by Att Righ's comment):

Setting `org-goto-interface` to one of the two recognised values does not mean sacrificing the alternative interface. Calling `org-goto` with a prefix argument (i.e. `C-u C-c C-j` or `C-u M-x org-goto RET`) automatically selects the alternative interface for the current completion. This way, you can set `org-goto-interface` to the interface you are likely to use most often and use the prefix argument when you wish to temporarily switch behaviour. If even this does not suit your needs, you can always write your own wrapper around `org-goto`, as per Att Righ's example.

Comment: > forgo the default org-goto behaviour, you can work around this by using a let binding around the functional call `(defun my-org-goto () (let ((org-goto-interface 'outline-path-completion)) (org-goto)))`

Comment: `outline-path-completion` does not play nicely with `helm` on my box (it can't complete past one level - achieved by pressing `<TAB>` if `helm ` is disabled: see `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`)

Comment: @AttRigh Sure, `let`-expressions can be used for any sort of temporary binding; this question is more about relevant settings/functionality/packages. A more general way to achieve a temporary switch of interface is to call `org-goto` with a prefix argument. I'll add a note to this answer.

Comment: @AttRigh I remember seeing something similar with `ivy`, but only when refiling and with an incorrect depth setting in `org-refile-targets`, as `org-goto` temporarily adapts refile-relevant settings to suit its needs. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to explore the `helm` functionality at the moment, perhaps another user can chime in?

Comment: thanks @Basil for the detaild answer. Unfortunately, the completion in this approach does not work as well as `worf` or `counsel-imenu`.

Comment: @ninrod Fair enough, I'm inspired to have a look at these myself now. :)

Comment: @Basil, actually, org-goto is my preferred method now because it maintains the tree context while worf does not.

Comment: Is it possible to activate follow-mode?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Of course, but I don't see how that relates to this Q&A.

Comment: I meant, I want to jump to a headline, but first I see the potential matcched headlines in the mini-buffer. TO have more context, how to activate follow-mode?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Ah, you mean you want the buffer position to update during completion? (`follow-mode` is a built-in mode that does something different.) My guess is that would depend on your completion frontend, e.g. Counsel has `counsel-org-goto` which auto-reveals completion candidates when `ivy-calling` is on. If your favourite completion frontend doesn't support this, my guess is you would have to write this behaviour yourself. But I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 9):

I use the package [worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf), but I bind only one of its functions:

```
 (use-package worf
    :diminish worf-mode
    :bind (:map org-mode-map ("C-c h" . worf-goto)))
```

`worf-goto` gives you a list of the headings in the buffer in the mini buffer, which you can then filter.

The package is made by the author of [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), so if you like ivy, you might like worf.

Some relevant snippets from [worf.el:](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf/blob/master/worf.el)

```
;;  - "g" (`worf-goto'): select an outline in the current buffer, with
;;    completion.  It's very good when you want to search/navigate to
;;    a heading by word or level. See https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy
;;    for a package that uses this method to navigate Lisp code.

(defun worf-goto-action (x)
  (with-ivy-window
    (goto-char (cdr x))
    (outline-show-children 1000)
    (worf-more)))

(defun worf-goto ()
  "Jump to a heading with completion."
  (interactive)
  (let ((cands (worf--goto-candidates)))
    (cond ((eq worf-completion-method 'helm)
           (require 'helm-multi-match)
           (let (helm-update-blacklist-regexps
                 helm-candidate-number-limit)
             (helm :sources
                   `((name . "Headings")
                     (candidates . ,cands)
                     (action . worf-goto-action)
                     (pattern-transformer . worf--pattern-transformer)))))
          ((eq worf-completion-method 'ivy)
           (ivy-read "Heading: " cands
                     :action 'worf-goto-action)))))
```

Comment: thanks @tirocinium. `counsel-imenu` completion works better than worf but can't search through level1 org headlines. worfs searches all levels, so I think this what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ninrod Have you tried setting `org-imenu-depth` to something greater than the default of 2?

Answer (score 5):

I find helm-org-rifle particularly nice. 
Also anything that takes imenu source will be able to display headers (e. g. Helm with imenu).

Comment: It should be noted that `helm-org-rifle` searches the *content* of org entries in addition to their titles. I found no way to alter this behaviour. `helm-org-rifle` references `org-search-goto` which does search all headlines but doesn't really support fuzzy searching.

Comment: Att Righ is right, `helm-org-rifle` does not search only headings.  It could be expanded to do this, but there's little reason to do so, since `helm-org-in-buffer-headings`, etc. exist in Helm itself.

Answer (score 5):

`imenu` is built into Emacs and can be paired with helm/ivy to provide the fuzzy search required. I'd recommend `helm-org-rifle` if you use helm, however.

Answer (score 4):

I use `counsel-imenu`; it will list the different heads, you can type some letters to narrow your selection and then just press `<return>`.

Comment: hi @gnuvince. this does not allow me to jump to level 1 org files right?

Answer (score 4):

Flagrant self-promotion, but you might like to try out [orgnav](https://github.com/facetframer/orgnav). Which is my kind of alpha (but actively used by me) project for this purpose.

*orgnav* searches headlines rather than content, can vary the depth of search, search subtrees rather than the entire file (though this can also be achieved with narrowing).

Here's a video of some features: https://asciinema.org/a/1r0fp33xgwh48lfgsh7mllw4u

You should probably also be aware of `helm-org` package which is part of `helm` which was the inspiration for this package (or rather whose limitations were the inspiration for this package), as well as `helm-org-rifle` discussed in other posts.

(Courtesy of answers here: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/69mc6l/how_to_jump_directly_to_an_orgheadline/
)
Also potentially of interest is the `worf-goto` function as part of `worf` (an org navigation mode that applies a different set of keybindings over "*" before headlines). This seems very much analogous to `helm-org`.

Answer (score 4):

The [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) library has a new feature in 0.9.0, which is completion for headlines of files in your org-agenda-files.

> counsel-org-agenda-headlines

Just need to setup your agenda files list in org init.

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/org/work.org"
                             "~/org/school.org" 
                             "~/org/home.org"))
```

In relation to @tirocinium's answer, this provides the same but for many agenda files.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `helm-org-in-buffer-headings`.  It's built-in to Helm, and it respects narrowed buffers, which is important if you use indirect buffers to edit subtrees independently.  There's also `helm-org-parent-headings` for navigating up a tree, and `helm-org-agenda-files-headings` for navigating across all agenda files.