# Search across tags / titles in org mode

Tags: org-mode, search

I keep some files in RST and `rst-mode` has `C-c C-t C-t runs the command rst-toc` which open all section titles in separate buffer. I can search ignoring actual document content which tends to have massive amount of searched term (so `occur` or `isearch` is a wasting of time).

Other files I keep in `.org` files.

Can I search / isearch only by section titles?

I'd like to keep using `.org` mode as I set convenient archiving of old info.

Comment: If you are using swiper, ivy, counsel etc. then you  might want to try `counsel-org-goto` which provides completion for org headings.

Comment: No, I don't use any of those. `ido` is my choice. And I am interested in searching/moving to section instead of completion.

Comment: I would say that the command does what you want, i.e. searching and moving and a `toc` is presented in the minibuffer. Anyway there is also the built in `org-goto`. This question and answers might be of some help https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32617/how-to-jump-directly-to-an-org-headline

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html):

> If you place an asterisk at the beginning of your search, Org-mode
>   will search only headlines (and not entry text).

This is in the agenda view. So if you are interested only in the current file, in the agenda menu, press `<` to restrict to the current buffer, and then select `s` for search. Then type in the term, but prepend it with `*`.

You can do more advanced queries (e.g. search for all headings with foo, but not with bar:

`*+foo -bar`

Now I wonder if there's a way to do it with `C-c /` instead of going through the agenda view...

Comment: embarrassed to say how long I've been looking for this.  Since before emacs.stackexchange existed.Thank you.